# Auto layout completes animation in much less than the time provided

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, swift2

I want to animate a container width in 10 seconds (for example). I have two views and I assign size constraints to both of them, and call the empty `init()` method. The problem I'm having - the "animation" is over before you know it, even though I have 10 seconds in for the duration. What gives?

This is a reproducible example of the issue.

```
class ContainerView: UIView {}
class ChildView: UIView {}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   var containerView: ContainerView!
   var childView: ChildView!

   var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      containerView = ContainerView()
      containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

      childView = ChildView()
      childView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

      containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

      containerView.addSubview(childView)
      view.addSubview(containerView)

      // Constraints
      let containerWidthNumber: CGFloat = 200
      let childWidthNumber: CGFloat = 100
      let containerWidth = NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: containerWidthNumber)
      let containerHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: containerWidthNumber)
      containerView.addConstraints([
         containerWidth,
         containerHeight,
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
      ])

      widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: childWidthNumber)
      let childHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: childWidthNumber)
      childView.addConstraints([
         widthConstraint,
         childHeight,
      ])

      view.addConstraints([
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
      ])
   }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
      super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

      self.widthConstraint.constant = 50
      UIView.animateWithDuration(10, animations: {

         self.childView.layoutIfNeeded()
      }, completion: { (success: Bool) in
         if success {
            print("good")
         }
      })
   }
}
```

Comment: Change the constraint outside of the `animateWithDuration` and simply have `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` in the animation block

Comment: Hey @Paulw11, thanks for the suggestion, but did you actually try it? Because it has no effect.

Comment: That is how I perform animations when I need to, for example, adjust for the appearance of the keyboard.

Comment: Sure, I get that, i do the same, but in this case it has no effect. That's the reason I posted all of the code needed to reproduce this, because it's so weird.

Comment: What version of Swift/Xcode are you using?  Your code didn't compile for me with Xcode 6.4 until I made some changes - the event to `touchesBegan` is not optional and I had to call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)` rather than assigning to the property.  Once those changes were made the animation worked correctly (i.e. it took 10 seconds)

Comment: I'm using the latest Xcode 7 beta. So yeah, I don't have access to the old ways of doing things. Thanks for your anyhow!

Comment: Looks like it is a bug in the beta then

Comment: @Paulw11 I think you should post this comment section as the answer, because I've confirmed your code. Thanks for the effort!